# multithreading issue in java

Tags: java, multithreading, jms

I am involved in a project where multithreading is used. Around 4-5 threads are spawned for every call (the system was developed for a taxi call center). The issue here is, after reading the information in the JMS queue a new thread has to spawn which is not happening. This problem occurs randomly. I [earlier posted similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703396/multiple-thread-spawning-in-my-java-application) in StackOverflow where I was advised to do load injection.

After studying about load injection I felt that, it is not feasible to do a test in my development server, as my system will be accessed from a call flow which controls the user access. I spent some time studying about the JVM tuning and thread pooling. Approx this particular system process around 14K-15K calls/day and during peak hours it the queue will be very high (might hit 400-500 calls waiting in the queue) for each calls around 4-5 threads has to be spawned. From the logs I don't see any thing like on OutOfMemoryError. **Is there any other reason which might stop spawning of thread?**

My JVM conf is xms:128m Xmx:1024m 
Environment is windows server 32bit, 4GB ram.

Will including the threadstacksize help spawning the thread without any hindrance?

I am also studying the feasibility of thread pooling. While spawning a fixed amount of threads I need to study whether it will impact the systems overall performance?

Comment: It's not impossible that the OS limits the amount of threads you can have concurrently active. Not putting this in an answer because I'm not sure how this affects JVMs (e.g. if they do anything to hide this limit from the user code).

Comment: I would definitely recommend going down the thread pool route, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating a thread is a very expensive operation** and uses a lot of system resources. Most importantly each thread needs a lot of memory for its stack (512 kB by default). If you excessively create new threads, you will run into all sorts of problems. A JVM can typically only support a couple of thousand of threads, depending on the operating system, the `-XX:ThreadStackSize` setting and the free memory.

Thread pooling will not make your performance worse, it will make it better. So you should definitely go that way. If your thread pool size is too small, you might have some liveness problems, but that is easy to tune.

Comment: I agree with u regarding the limitations. But is there any way that we can find out the amount of active thread the OS is processing.

Comment: Use a profiler, such as [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changes in the architecture can help solve the problem  - I'd try thread pooling because of its efficiency but alone it is not guaranteed to solve the problem. It is possible the you'll need to **reconsider if all the spawned threads are really needed** (having multiple threads competing for single resource is perf. impact) and **tune the size of the pools**. Look at **Executor**, it could help you with some changes.

Comment: Cant consider re-structuring the architecture, as this project was developed by someone else. I took over from him when he quit. And also its in production now. U see my problem stuck some were. have to some how fix this issue.